# Specify scope for Meteor link-accounts package?

Tags: javascript, google-api, meteor-accounts

I'm using the [link-accounts](https://github.com/yubozhao/meteor-link-accounts) meteor package to acquire OAuth credentials for the [Google Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/).

I need to request the `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds` scope in order to make the API calls, and so I attempted to link the google account as such:

```
Meteor.linkWithGoogle({
  scope: [
    'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds'
  ]
}, (error) => {
  ...
});
```

However, when I inspect `user.services.google` afterward, it only shows the scopes I specified in the Google API Console for this project, which are:

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile`

The `m8/feeds` scope is not an option in the Google API Console to enable, so **how can I explicitly request the scope that I need without enabling ?** I figured passing it in as an option to the `linkWithGoogle` call would work, but this didn't seem to do a thing.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Changing `scope` to `requestPermissions` solved the issue:

```
Meteor.linkWithGoogle({
  requestPermissions: [
    'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds'
  ]
}, ...
```